# React app with multi-tenant support with single codebase to support multiple clients with only configuration to push for that client

Tags: reactjs, vite

I want to develop an application which I want to give to multiple clients (with different hosting, database and API).

I am trying to create similar codebase and want to change the static content logo, text, json binding for some statics records, address, images, title, address, phone etc.

what is the best approach to achieve my requirement?

1. Replace the static content on build similar like environment variable.
2. Smaller JSON to avoid the performance issue.
3. GitHub configuration such a way that I don't have to unnecessary push to other tenant configuration in the production codebase.

I thought of below approaches.

a) Environment variable: It is good approach because it will replace the environment variable when publish to the production. I want to know how to setup in local where I can run yarn dev tenan1env or run yarn dev tenan2env to keep single codebase. Once it's deployed to production then yarn build tenant1env.

2. Above approach has limitation of maximum limit of environment variable. Hence, I thought to create small Json in different folders and parent folder with tenant name so it will pick based on the tenant selected from the above approach.

Please suggest me the best for longer support.